# Integral of exponential using error function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, normal-distribution, exponential-function, error-function

I'm trying to solve some integrals below

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {x^n e^\frac{-(x - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2}}dx$$

I am interested in the solutions where n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

I have learned that integrals of this form can't be solved the usual way, but can be evaluated in terms of the error function.

I've checked using [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20%28x%29%20%2a%20e%5E-%28%28%28x-u%29%5E2%29/%28s%2as%29%29%20dx) and it seems that the solutions are indeed expressable using the error function, however I've no idea how the solution was reached.

Comment: I believe it is a well known integral in statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856225/compute-int-0-inftye-tzzdn-1dz-as-a-function-of-gamman/856525#856525). Here is a nice formula in terms of a friendly function, the gamma function

> $$ I = \frac{\mu^n\sigma}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}((-1)^k+1){n\choose k}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\mu}\right)^k \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \right),$$

where ${n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ and $\Gamma(x)$ is the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). I'll provide a proof when the time allows.

**Note:** I'll appreciate it if someone double check the formula.

**Added:** If you are interested in the proof you can follow the steps:

1) make the change of variables $t=x-\mu$

2) use the binomial theorem

3) split the range of integration on the intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$

4) for the integral on the interval $(-\infty,0)$ make the change of variables $u=-t$,

5) use the change of variables $y=t^2/\sigma^2$ and the Gamma function.

then you are done.

Answer (score 1):

This integral is $I=\sqrt{\pi\sigma^2}\cdot E(X^n)$ where the random variable $X$ is normal $(\mu,\sigma^2/2)$ hence $X=\mu+(\sigma/\sqrt2) Z$ where  the random variable $Z$ is standard normal, and
$$
I=\sqrt{\pi\sigma^2}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\mu^{n-k}(\sigma/\sqrt2)^kE(Z^k).
$$
One knows that, for every nonnegative integer $k$, $E(Z^{2k+1})=0$ and
$$
E(Z^{2k})=(2k-1)(2k-3)\cdots1=(2k-1)!!=\frac{\Gamma(2k)}{2^{k-1}\Gamma(k)},
$$
hence
$$
I=\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\sum_{0\leqslant2k\leqslant n}{n\choose 2k}\mu^{n-2k}\sigma^{k+1}\frac{\Gamma(2k)}{2^{2k-1}\Gamma(k)}.
$$

Comment: good idea :) , although its not quite in standard normal form. I think a change of variable is required. I used g = (1/(2^0.5))*sigma. So I = (2*pi*g*g)^0.5 *E(X^n)

Comment: Right, the variance is sigma^2/2, not sigma^2. See revised version.

Comment: @Did: I already worked the problem out for him from scratch.