# Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tz}(z+d)^{n-1}dz$ as a function of $\Gamma(n)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Is it possible to compute this integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tz}(z+d)^{n-1}dz$$ as a function of complete gamma  $\Gamma(n)$. If possible, I'm looking for a closed form solution.

Thanks!

Comment: If $n$ is an natural number, then yes. Did you try to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: In my case, $n$ isn't a natural number. I tried to solve the problem but i got something function of incomplete gamma.

Comment: Maple gives $$e^{dt}*\Gamma(n, d*t)*t^{-n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to compute the integral as a function of $\Gamma(n)$

The integral is an Incomplete Gamma function. Change the variable $Z=t(z+d)$ and the integral definition of the Incomplete Gamma appears.

$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tz}(z+d)^{n-1}dz = e^{td}t^{-n}\int_{td}^{\infty}e^{-Z}Z^{n-1}dZ = e^{td}t^{-n}\Gamma(n,td)$

Answer (score 0):

A [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794070/integral-of-exponential-using-error-function/794100#794100). Here is a closed form for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Recalling the binomial theorem and making the change of variables $u=tz$ we have
$$I= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tz}(z+d)^{n-1}dz = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}(u/t+d)^{n-1}\frac{du}{t} $$

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k} \frac{d^{n-1-k}}{t^k} \int_{0}^{\infty}u^{k}e^{-u}du $$

> $$ \implies  I= d^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k} \frac{1}{(td)^k}\Gamma(k+1) $$

**Added:** If $n$ is not a natural number then you can consider [Newton's generalised binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) as stated in the comment by Cameron Williams.

Comment: As stated by OP, $n$ is not necessarily an integer. However by using Newton's generalization, your approach is more or less correct anyways.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: It is not stated in the question itself. I just paid attention to this matter after your comment. I can see this in the comments. Thank you for your comment. I appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah I figured you hadn't seen it which is why I commented but as I said, your approach would carry over quite quickly anyway.